# How do I decode a webpage using Requests and BeatifulSoup library in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tied writing some code for a project I am doing. First, I'll show you my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://github.com'
r = requests.get(url)
r_html = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r_html, "html.parser")
title = soup.find('span', 'articletitle')
```

The project is to be able to decode a webpage. Basicaly in the variable url, you put in any url and use python for it to return back the basic html code back in a txt format. I am using the requests and BeautifulSoup library for Python.

I tried running this code, and it should be right but when it runs, it doesn't return anything. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try `print(r_html)` ?

Comment: `articletitle` does not appear in the source HTML of this webpage

Comment: can you tell me what is this `articletitle` in your code?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. I formatted the code differently and it works.